# USB connected mouse stops working randomly

Tags: windows, usb, mouse, power

Lately my mouse stops working all of the time and then starts working for a bit again. This is the same no matter what mouse or USB port I use. I have searched stack overflow for a solution but found none that where relevant.

On two ports I get a message that the device needs more power than the usb port can put out. On one I don't get that message but still have the same problem. It started a couple of weeks ago and has gotten increasingly worse. Sometimes the mouse will work fine for 30 minutes then shut off and sometimes it will work for 2 minutes before starting to flip back and forth between on and off.

What can I do? Is my USB controller screwed? I am using an ASUS laptop with model name R552JK. Windows 10.

Comment: Does the mouse work OK on a different computer? Does a different mouse work OK on this computer?

Comment: Yes, I have tried three different mice and they all have the same problem on my laptop but work fine on other computers.

Comment: Then the problem is with your local computer. Another question: Do other USB devices work OK on your laptop? Can you try connecting a USB hub to your computer and connect the mouse to it? But, the long and short of this is: Your computer has a hardware fault and you should either pursue warranty repair or seek local qualified hardware repair services.

Comment: Thank you for your input, much appreciated. USB drives work fine, that is the only thing I have to test with. I will have to buy a USB hub and test. The computer is out of warranty just a couple of weeks ago so I can't go that route. I guess I will have to bite the bullet and get a new computer or repair it (that's usually really expensive so it might be more economical to buy a new one). Shame though since everything is working alright.

Comment: Try the USB hub before you toss the computer.

Comment: I fixed it. Or it fixed itself, not sure what happened to be honest. I think the mice I tried where all faulty but worked temporarily when I tried them both on this laptop and the other computers.

So I bought a logitech 503 mouse with an USB-cordless receiver and the mouse works absolutely fine. No issues at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the mouse was faulty and replacing the mouse resolved the issue.

Comment: Yes, seems fair. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @music2myear: Why does that make it off-topic? Can you provide a reference? E.g., to a meta post.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, this is 3 years old, and OP just replaced the mouse rather than searching out a deeper issue. They chose not to answer the question and so there's no reason for it to remain open. It might not be off topic, but it should be closed and deleted.